# Keeping a whole table on one page

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have a MS Word 2010 document with many small tables. I would like to prevent those tables from breaking up over pages. I know it is possible to prevent a single row to break up. But I would like the following:

1. How can I prevent a table from breaking up over several pages?
2. How can I do this for one or several tables at the time, instead of setting it per row?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Yes you can. Highlight the entire table by clicking the icon with the arrows at the top left of the table. Then click **Paragraph Properties** from the toolbar and tick **Keep with Next**.

Comment: Screenshots available here: http://superuser.com/a/379919/156700

Comment: If you select the table last row, the text after the table will also be kept together, to prevent that, don't select the last table row.

Comment: Any Ideas why this would fail?  It does not work.

Comment: Keep with next in Office 2010 https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/keep-with-next-word-2010/877a26d8-b388-49bf-8f88-a92c37d08af9

Comment: Not seeing this option on Mac :(

Comment: This option is in Word 16.25 for Mac, but does not affect the table.

Comment: This had no effect for me, using Office 365 (on a fairly large table, about 3/4 of the page).  My posted solution ('page break before' on first row) resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to "special" paste the Excel information into the Word document as a picture.  This allows you to resize the entire table to fit on a single page.  Drag a corner of the table-picture to ensure the ratio of the sides to the top and bottom stay the same.  The drawback is that a reader can't copy your table into Excel and do more with it nor can they add columns or rows in Word.  I like to do this when I want to ensure someone won't mess with my numbers, but still might want to edit the wording.

Comment: IMHO, this is a bad answer — but it *is **an answer***. Downvoters, fire away; but I believe that it should not be deleted.

Comment: Is is a good answer for certain situations.

Answer (score 1):

If your whole table will fit on one page, but is being pushed onto the next page due to previous content (e.g. in a situation where the table starts half-way down the page), you may be tempted to insert a manual page-break before the table so it starts at the top of the next page.

However, this will also add a blank line at the top of the page, above the table, and there doesn't seem to be a good way to get rid of this (aside from setting it to 1pt font, with no paragraph spacing, which is an ugly hack and somewhat fiddly).

An alternative approach that inserts a break without any additional whitespace is to select the first row of the table. Then click Paragraph Properties from the toolbar and tick 'Page Break Before'.  This will force the table to the top of the next page without any additional white-space.

This won't solve the issue if your table is too big for a single page (scaling-down font sizes and other similar attributes is probably the only choice there) and it may need reverting if subsequent edits free up enough space to remove the need for a page break, but it is a good solution for some situations.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I was inserting a table from Excel into Word. Since the table was too long to stay on one page I copied as much of the table that fit, pasted it in Word, then pasted the rest of the table right next to it.

So basically you can just create the table in parts so it fits on one page.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a setting to allow the entire table to stay on the same page, simply because your table may be too long to contain within a single page.

You can get the table on its own page by inserting a page break before and after the table.
From the Insert menu choose Break > Page Break to insert a manual page break.

You can also adjust properties for multiple rows os a table by selecting the whole table before setting row properties. Hover on the top left corner of the table to get the table selection icon which looks like a + with arrows on its ends.