# Keep tables from breaking across pages

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

The picture herebelow displays a table in Word 2013 which has been split up in a page transition:

[image]

My goal is to keep the integrity of this table, disallowing it to appear partially in two pages at once.

I have tried to no avail unchecking the box **Allow row to break across pages**, as shown in the following:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: The row setting would only apply to an individual row. I can't see a way to do this within the Table Properties dialog, but you could insert a page break ahead of the table, which would always force it to start on a new page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keeping a whole table on one page](http://superuser.com/questions/515543/keeping-a-whole-table-on-one-page)